# Java: Multiply two list which are Stream<BigDecimal>

Tags: enums

I know my Question is a little for beginners, but in Internet I didn't find Answer, So It's good to have,
I have a list which contain two value, first an Enum Type, second a big decimal Number. In my Enum Class, I have also two values related to each Enum, the first value is a string and the second is a BigDecimal.

Enum:

```
    private enum myEnumClass {
  BMW("Karl Rapp", new BigDecimal("1916")), BENZ("Carl Benz", new BigDecimal("1926")),
  private String founder;
  private BigDecimal yearOfFoundation;
```

List:

```
List<CarDetails> numberOfcars = new ArrayList<>();
numberOfcars.add(new CarDetails(BMW, new BigDecimal("3")));
CarDetails.add(new Receipt(BENZ, new BigDecimal("5")));
```

CarDetails Class:

```
    class CarDetails {
  myEnumClass carCompany;
  BigDecimal amountOfCar;
```

I want to multiply yearOfFundation to numberOfCar for each company, so like:

```
for BMW=1916*3;
for BENZ= 1926*5;
and then plus them: (1916*3)(1926*5);
```

I want to use Stream() I think it might be possible, but the problem is when I use stream I get this Datatyp: Stram, which not Allows me to use: BigDecimal.multiply(BigDecimal).
any idea how can I write is correctly?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `BigDecimal` is not an appropriate type to represent a year. Instead, use [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) or `int`/`Integer`. Or is this a contrived example, not your real business scenario?

Comment: `BigDecimal` is for numbers with a decimal fraction. Can you have year 1916, 1916.1, 1916.2376532178? Otherwise choose a different type as @BasilBourque already suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Using [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), You could do something like this

```
BigDecimal res = numberOfcars
    .stream()
    .reduce(
        BigDecimal.ZERO,
        (BigDecimal acc, CarDetails c) -> acc.add(
            c.getAmountOfCar().multiply(c.getCarCompany().getYearOfFoundation())
        ),
        BigDecimal::add
    );
```

[Demo](https://www.online-java.com/TjZRSfXszH)